# WARNING: erroneous pipeline: no element "rtmpsink"

Tags: nginx, ubuntu-12.04, rtmp

I execute

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v v4l2src ! 'video/x-raw, width=1024, height=768, 
framerate=30/1' ! queue ! videoconvert ! h264parse ! flvmux ! rtmpsink 
location='rtmp://10.168.45.142/live live=1'
```

An error occurred：
    warning erroneous pipeline no element rtmpsink

the nginx service has started, the configuration is as follows, how can I solve it?

```
rtmp {
    server {
        listen 1935;
        chunk_size 4096;
        application live {
            live on;
            record off;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have all plugins installed for gstreamer. 
After intsalling `gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad` it will work.

```
sudo apt-get install gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad
```